# All of a sudden i got an error Page crashed in playwright goto function

Tags: google-chrome, playwright

````
Error: page.goto: Page crashed
Call log:

- navigating to "https://www.whateveritis.com/", waiting until "load"

```
test("Check Hover Functionality for menu",async ({page,baseURL})=>{
   await page.goto(baseURL)
   await HomePageFlow.validateHomePage(page)
   await HomePageFlow.visitCategoryFromHomePage(homepagedata, page)
}
```
````

NOTE: I am facing this issue only Chrome, apart from the webkit is working fine.

**package.json file**

```
    {
      "name": "webautomation",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {},
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@playwright/test": "^1.40.1",
        "@types/node": "^20.10.5"
      }
    }
```

**test spec file code is**

```
test("open google",async ({page})=>{
      await page.goto("https://www.google.com");
   }
```

Comment: None of the code here is reproducible. We'll need to see your config, package.json, `HomePageFlow` and the URL to be able to take action here. Code should be complete and runnable, and expected goal should be provided. Thanks.

Comment: I update the description as per you please check 
Thanks